# Cannot run an update: entity_test module is missing

Tags: 8, updating

I've got this error after trying to update to the last Drupal 8 (8.3.2):

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "entity_test" entity type does not exist. dans Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (ligne 133 de /var/www/prod/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).

How can I install or uninstall this module?

it seems a system module, so I cannot install it.

Comment: That is from a test module from core.  Do you have `$settings['extension_discovery_scan_tests'] = TRUE;` in your settings?

Comment: Also, 8.3.3 hasn't been tagged yet; the latest is 8.3.2.  What version are you upgrading from?

Comment: And what is the backtrace for that error? it is a test module, it must not be enabled on a real site.

Comment: Hi there, I put $settings['extension_discovery_scan_tests'] = FALSE; everywhere.

I don't call the settings.debug on production.

The exact backtrace is : 

module system

Update add_region_to_entity_displays

Failure : Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException : The "entity_test" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 133 from /var/www/prod/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).